# Read Raw JSON Array from MySQL in Node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have a question. How to get a JSON array from MySQL in Node.js return that data pure the same as the database. Always o Node.js change the structure.

```
[
  {
    "radius": "1",
    "minorder": "2",
    "deliveryfee": "3"
  },
  {
    "radius": "5",
    "minorder": "4",
    "deliveryfee": "5"
  }
]}
```

Mysql Nodejs return me that way

```
[
  {
    "settings_deliveryzone": [
      {
        "radius": "1",
        "minorder": "2",
        "deliveryfee": "3"
      },
      {
        "radius": "5",
        "minorder": "4",
        "deliveryfee": "5"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

My Code is

```
    async viewsettingsdelivery(request, response){
    mysql.getConnection((err, conn) => {
        const id_user  = request.headers.authorization;
        if (err) { return response.status(500).send({ error: error }) }
            conn.query('SELECT settings_deliveryzone FROM users WHERE id = ?', [id_user], function (err, result, fields) {
                // if any error while executing above query, throw error
                if (err) throw err;
                return response.json(result);
        })
    })}
```

I tried a lot of times, without success. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be

```
'SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(settings_deliveryzone,'$[0].settings_deliveryzone') FROM users WHERE id = ?'
```

If settings_deliveryzone is a json.

following query

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT('[{ "settings_deliveryzone": [{         "radius": "1",          "minorder": "2", "deliveryfee": "3"},{"radius": "5","minorder": "4","deliveryfee": "5"}]}]'
```

,'$[0].settings_deliveryzone')

Results in

```
JSON_EXTRACT('[{ "settings_deliveryzone": [{            "radius": "1",          "minorder": "2", "deliveryfee": "3"},{"radius": "5","minorder": "4","deliveryfee": "5"}]}]'
,'$[0].settings_deliveryzone')
[{"radius": "1", "minorder": "2", "deliveryfee": "3"}, {"radius": "5", "minorder": "4", "deliveryfee": "5"}]
```

Comment: I don't think the JSON stored in the database actually contains the key "settings_deliveryzone." He's just printing the entire result set from MySQL instead of the column he wants.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has to identify each column in the result set because you can obviously select more than one column.

Imagine your query was:

```
SELECT settings_deliveryzone, name FROM users WHERE id = ?
```

You're going get back an array (because the query can return multiple rows), and each element of that array is going to have two members, `settings_deliveryzone` and `name`.

```
[
  {
    "settings_deliveryzone": [
      {
        "radius": "1",
        "minorder": "2",
        "deliveryfee": "3"
      },
      {
        "radius": "5",
        "minorder": "4",
        "deliveryfee": "5"
      }
    ],
    "name": "Herbert Amaro Santana"
  }
]
```